# How to debug R code in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, r, debugging, breakpoints

I have been coding a lot of R code for the past few year but I actually never found how to debug R code (i am using Eclipse) and it has been very frustrating and time consuming.
Do you know if it is possible now? (breakpoints etc..) It seems for some reason it was not available.

Could you please kindly point to any tutorial,

Thanks

Comment: This might get you started: http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/debuggingR/debug.shtml / Edit: you might consider trying out RStudio Desktop (eclipse based AFAIK), it allows you to single step through your code (see http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/using/source Section Executing Code).

Comment: Try `debug(myfunctioname())`, and then run `myfunctionname( arg1 = val , arg2 = val2 ... etc)` with the appropriate arguments. Did you actually Google [*debugging in R*](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/debuggingR/)?!!

Comment: Simon, debug() is not what i call debugging. it is actually even worse than running the function itself with arguments set in the console. You really start enjoy debug() when you have a loop with 500 steps and you have to press Enter 500 times.

Answer (score 1):

This eclipse plug-in is helpful for debugging R codes:

http://www.walware.de/goto/statet

Answer (score 0):

Not in eclipse but R has a fine debuger package.

```
install.packages("debug")
library(debug)
f = function(x){ print("hello"); return(x+1);}
mtrace(f,T)
f(1) # this will open a debug window
mtrace(f,F) # to stop the function from being debugged (or traced)
```